# Using Bigquery Table wildcards with relative date range and Standard SQL

Tags: google-bigquery

I frequently run queries over the last N days (typically 14 or 30) of data in bigquery using legacy SQL as follows:

```
  SELECT
    …
  FROM
    TABLE_DATE_RANGE([XXX_], DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -30, 'DAY'), DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 0, 'DAY'))
  WHERE
    …
```

I would like to switch this query to use Standard SQL instead of Legacy SQL. I know how to express `XXX_YYYYMMDD` using wildcards, and I know how to express a specific range of dates with something like `XXX_2017*`, but I do not know how to express a relative range such as the last 30 days.

How do I convert the above query to Standard SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works for you:

```
SELECT 
  date
FROM `dataset.table_*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)) AND FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 0 DAY))
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY DATE
```

Where the wildcard in this example is selecting dates in the format`"%Y%m%d"`. You can choose which format is more appropriate to your wildcard selection.